# How is x += 1 <= y evaluated in Python?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

How is `x += 1 <= y` evaluated in Python?

Intuitively I assume it is `x += (1 <= 2)` but it seems to be `(x += 1) <= 2`, however without any return value and `x += 1` returning the value of x before the operation is executed. An explanation would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: "but it seems to be (x += 1) <= 2" - what could make you think that??

Comment: Use `print(ast.dump(ast.parse("x += 1 <= y").body[0], indent=4))` to see for yourself how Python parses it. It's an assignment involving a comparison expression, not a comparison expression involving an assignment.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille They're assuming `x += 1` is an expression with a side effect, because `x` winds up being incremented by 1 under either assumption as long as y is not less than 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the assignment operators have lower precedence than the comparison operators, so it is evaluated as `x += (1 <= y)`.

```
>>> x = 3
>>> y = 7
>>> x += 1 <= y
>>> x
4
```

`1 <= y` is True, which has the value 1, and 1 is added to `x`.

Python does not treat assignment operators like C.  You cannot use them in mid-expression, so:

```
>>> z = (x+=1) + (x+=1)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    z = (x+=1) + (x+=1)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

The conditional `1 <= y` is executed first. This results in a boolean (true or false). As python is dynamically typed, python treats `x += true` as `x += 1`.

Comment: Python is not "loosely typed"; `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant dynamically. Will update.

Comment: It's dynamically typed, but that has nothing to do with why `True == 1`.